# How can I build my own kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, gnu, drivers

My Hp-envy laptop deson't boot any linux distro , so someone called mike found a sol. and he posted the files on github 
but without any info about how to use it or how to build my own linux kernel and how to integrate it into a distro

mike github ripo : https://github.com/mikejonesey/hp-envy-15-ah150sa

mike website : http://www.mikejonesey.co.uk/linux/hp-envy-15-ah150sa

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: **Way** too broad, see [ask]